# Can anyone help with serpentine belt diagram for K7M engine(Renault Sandero)?

Tags: serpentine-belt, drive-belt

Renault Sandero(K7M) 1.6 8v.

I have taken the belt off to inspect it, and now am wanting to put it back.

I made a diagram but I'm starting wonder if I made an error in the routing of the belt over the various pulleys and wheels. Visibility is somewhat limited.

Does someone have an idea as to the correct order of the routing?

Comment: How many pulleys are there?  Does it have air conditioning?

Comment: Yes.It has aircon and power steering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this diagram which I believe is for your engine [here](https://edukr.ru/en/tire/dvigatel-k7m-ot-reno-harakteristiki-remont-i-servisnoe/).

[image]

Comment: Superb, @HandyHowie.

Thanks for that.